# Pact >> Pact Provider host other than localhost

Tags: provider, pact

I'm using pact java > Pact verify works when the provider host is localhost.
How do I provide some other host details?
When I specify a provider like this,

---

```
<serviceProvider>
   <name>provider1</name>
   <protocol>http</protocol>
   **<host>**google.com**</host>**
   <path>/</path>

   <consumers>
    <consumer>
    <name>consumer1</name>
    <pactFile>../pacts/test_consumer-test_provider.json</pactFile>
    </consumer>
    </consumers>
</serviceProvider>
```

I receive a response

---

```
Verifying a pact between consumer1 and provider1
  [Using file ../pacts/test_consumer-test_provider.json]
  Given test state
         WARNING: State Change ignored as there is no stateChange URL
  Invalid Information Model
      Request Failed - google.com
```

How do I provide some other host details?

Answer (score 4):

`google.com` is not a valid host, it is Google's base domain name. You should provide an actual host name to send the requests to.

For example, using curl to `google.com`:

```
$ curl -v http://google.com
* Rebuilt URL to: http://google.com/
*   Trying 216.58.203.110...
* Connected to google.com (216.58.203.110) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: google.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
< Location: http://www.google.com.au/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=ckz9WMKPDYTr8weL36iABA
< Content-Length: 262
< Date: Mon, 24 Apr 2017 00:53:06 GMT
< 
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com.au/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;ei=ckz9WMKPDYTr8weL36iABA">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

returns a `302 Moved` response.

If you run with debug logging enabled (-X parameter for maven), you should get more details as why the verifier treated the request as a failure.

Answer (score 0):

The host is the IP or hostname address of the Provider. So if you have your provider lets say somewhere deployed, you have to provide the IP address of that deployment. You can not just randomly provide HOSTNAMEs as google.com.